# Is it possible to get sender's ip address of message?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

In rabbitmq, the message's structure is:
-record('P_basic', {content_type, content_encoding, headers, delivery_mode, priority, correlation_id, reply_to, expiration, message_id, timestamp, type, user_id, app_id, cluster_id}).

But I want to record's the ip address for monitoring. How could I do?

Answer (score 1):

I would add this to a custom header property of the message when you publish it. I can't offer implementation details since I don't know what platform(s) you are using.

Comment: Does this solution depend on client's honest? debian linux platform.

Comment: Perhaps so. But, allowing the client to connect directly to your AMQP server depends much more upon it.